# Chrome SVG: Reusing animation element with fill="freeze" does not work as expected

Tags: svg

I am supporting some old SVG graphics that we have in our application. I am having some issues with animating the fill color of a rectangle, and I am wondering if anyone else has seen the same issue.

We setup an animate element on the rec which ends up looking like this:

```
<svg id="svgEle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<rect id="rect"
  width="100" height="100" 
  style="fill:#008000; stroke:#000000;">
    <animate id="animate" fill="freeze" 
      attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" 
      begin="indefinite" dur="1s"></animate>
  </rect>      
</svg>
```

And then, depending on values from a webservice result, we change the color of the rect and attempt to animate the color change.  Currently it seems as if Chrome is the only native SVG render that supports the beginElement function.  The animation works perfect on the first run, but all subsequent attempts to update the animation do not behave as expected. They always seem to revert to the first animation's fill color.

I have created the following example to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ssawchenko/ARXbs/

In Chrome the rectangle SHOULD cycle through all 4 colors via an animation when you click on the button, but it does not.  In IE9 animation is not supported, so the fill color is just changed directly.

I am ok with IE9 simply setting the fill, however, in Chrome the colors are completely busted. Does anyone know if this is a bug, or if there is a work around?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work as expected in both Firefox and Opera. Perhaps you should raise a bug on Webkit via https://bugs.webkit.org/

Answer (score 1):

This bug also exhibits in [SVG Edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html).

```
<animate attributeName="opacity" begin="indefinite" dur="1" fill="freeze">
</animate>
```

If you draw rectangles on top of each other you will see they seem semitransparent when they should be fully opaque. I've seen that Chrome Canary doesn't exhibit this behaviour, so it might be fixed in the next release.

I think [this filed bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104503&q=animate%20svg&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary) is related.